# Convert List<Object[]> into HashMap<Integer,List<String>> what can be a optimal way?

Tags: java, performance, list, hashmap, time-complexity

I have `List<Object[]>` say li with items like

```
li.add(new Object[]{1,"Orange"}) 
li.add(new Object[]{1,"Apple"}) 
li.add(new Object[]{1,"Orange"}) 
li.add(new Object[]{2,"Guava"}) 
li.add(new Object[]{3,"Apple"}) 
li.add(new Object[]{3,"Grapes"})
```

i.e. one Integer can be multiple times.Now I have to convert this List into  a HashMap `HashMap<Integer,List<String>>` 
types what can be a optimal way?

Comment: If you use a `HashMap<Integer, HashSet<String>>` the set will deal with duplicate strings for you...if thats what you want

Comment: If you care about performance as you state in your tags, please use an sparsearray as i explain in my answer below.  also, instead of an sparse of arralist, you can also consider an sparsearray of hashset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sequence of steps which can help you achieve it.

1. Iterate over the List.
2. For each element, check if the `Object[0]` is already present in the map.
   a. If present, then get the `List<String>` for that key and add the `Object[1]` to it.
   b. If not, then create a new `List<String>`, add the `Object[1]` to it and add an entry to the map with `Object[0]` as the key and the newly created List with the `Object[1]` added to it as the value.
3. Continue this till the end of the list.

*Note:* You need to cast your `Object[0]` to `Integer` and `Object[1]` as `String` wherever necessary.

Comment: Good suggestion but when to put in map can you explain by extending my example

Comment: @AshishMohan - I've covered everything required for the example you gave. What part do you need more clarity about?

Comment: Your solution will put only last string per key in map and not List<String>

Comment: No it wont. If you see the sub section (a) in point 2, you see that, you get the List<String> for that particular key and add the new String to it. This list will contain the previous strings too. As per the characteristics of Map, it'll have only 1 entry of that key with only 1 value, but that 1 value is a List contains all the strings read for that key till now.

Comment: But in the sub section (a) in point 2 you does not putting that list to map .You are only putting entry in 2(b).

Comment: Since the retrieved list from the map is referring to the list reference in the map, just adding an element to it will work. Try it out and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: @AshishMohan - Exactly. You can just search around for that in SO and get a lot of really good answers with detailed explanations! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid duplicate value in the value list in the map user HashSet in place of List

With HashSet

```
HashMap<Integer, HashSet<String>> map =new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<String>>();
for (Object[] objects : lst) {
HashSet<String> valueSet;
if(map.containsKey((Integer)objects[0])){
valueSet = map.get((Integer)objects[0]);
}
else{
   valueSet = new HashSet<String>();
   map.put((Integer)objects[0],valueSet);
}
valueSet.add((String)objects[1]);
}
System.out.println(map);
```

Using List

```
HashMap<Integer, List<String>> map =new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
for (Object[] objects : lst) {
List<String> valueList;
if(map.containsKey((Integer)objects[0])){
valueList = map.get((Integer)objects[0]);
}
else{
valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
map.put((Integer)objects[0],valueList);
}
valueList.add((String)objects[1]);
}
System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `SparseArray<ArrayList<String>>` that has better performance. 
Actually probably your IDE (eclipse does) will recommend you to change your `HashMap<Integer,List<String>>` to SparseArray

```
     SparseArray<ArrayList<String>> list;

      for (Object[] objects : yourlist) {

            Integer number=((Integer) objects[0]);
            String value=((String) objects[1]);
            if (list.get(number) == null) {
                 ArrayList<String> temp= new  ArrayList<String>(); 
                 temp.put(value);
                 list.append(number, temp);
            }
            else list.get(number).put(value);

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
    Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

    for (Object[] objects : li) {
        if (map.containsKey(objects[0])) {
            List<String> list = map.get(objects[0]);
            list.add((String) objects[1]);
            map.put((Integer) objects[0], list);
        } else {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add((String) objects[1]);
            map.put((Integer) objects[0], list);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: Your solution is good but can it be possible to remove duplicate entries from list

Comment: @AshishMohan, To remove duplicate use `Set` instead of `List`.